# Как совместить PHP_URL_HOST и PHP_URL_PATH?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить ссылку (домен + последний каталог), пример: вася.ру/каталог/

так

`$host = parse_url( preg_match('#^https?://#',$last_url) ? $last_url : 'http://'.$last_url, PHP_URL_HOST, PHP_URL_PATH ) or die('Не верное имя домена');`

и
так
`echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST, PHP_URL_PATH);`

не получается.

Как заменить на функцию basename() не знаю, помогите получить текущий каталог в этом коде 
`$host = parse_url( preg_match('#^https?://#',$last_url) ? $last_url : 'http://'.$last_url, PHP_URL_HOST, PHP_URL_PATH ) or die('Не верное имя домена');`

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему Вы так не делаете?

```
$last_url = 'https://вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3/file.html?id=5';
$parts_ur = parse_url($last_url);
//$parts_ur['scheme'] => https
//$parts_ur['host'] => вася.ру
//$parts_ur['path'] => /каталог1/каталог2/каталог3/file.html
//basename($parts_ur['path']) => file.html
//т.е. нужно если со схемой https://вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3/file.html

$output = $parts_ur['scheme'] . '://' . $parts_ur['host'] . $parts_ur['path'];
 //т.е. без схемы вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3/file.html
$output = $parts_ur['host'] . $parts_ur['path'];

//последний каталог 
$catalog=explode('/', $parts_ur['path']);
$last_catalog=$catalog[count($catalog)-2]; //$last_catalog =>каталог3

//каталоги без файла
    $without_file = implode('/',explode('/', $parts_ur['path'], -1)); //$without_file => каталог1/каталог2/каталог3

 //если домен и каталоги: https://вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3
     $output = $parts_ur['scheme'] . '://' . $parts_ur['host'] . $without_file;

//если домен и последний каталог: https://вася.ру/каталог3

     $output = $parts_ur['scheme'] . '://' . $parts_ur['host'] . '/'.$last_catalog;
```

Comment: Не понял, как результат получить. У меня ничего не отобразилось. Вникаю.

Comment: в  $output  результат. там 3 варианта. в первом - https:// вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3, во втором вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3, в третьем - https:// вася.ру/каталог3  - используйте то, что вам нужно

Comment: Сделал так `$output = $parts_ur['scheme'] . '://' . $parts_ur['host'] . $parts_ur['path'];
` она еще и файл на конце подхватывает, можно просто директорией ограничиться?

Comment: в первом - https:// вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3 если есть file.html то получаю https:// вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3/file.html  вместо https:// вася.ру/каталог1/каталог2/каталог3

Comment: Здорово! Спасибо!

Comment: А как убрать параметры на конце, пример `1811815914050622?&area_id=77655&user_id=123456`, оставить только `1811815914050622 `Перепробовал все варианты, не вышло   :( p.s. данную ссылку получаю через `' . basename( $item->url ) . '`

Comment: Из $path (1811815914050622?&area_id=77655&user_id=123456) удалить ?&area_id=77655&user_id=123456, оставить 1811815914050622

Comment: $parts_ur['query'] - все после знака вопроса ? , т.е area_id=77655&user_id=123456 часть должна уйти в эту переменную и в $parts_ur['path'] её не должно быть.... если из-за некоректного урл оно попало в $parts_ur['path'], разбейте строку с помощью $tmp=implode('?', $parts_ur['path']) и в $tmp[0] будет без get параметров

Comment: `if(preg_match_all("/<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\">.*?<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>/s", $js, $matches))
{
$n = count($matches[1]);
$html = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
$item->title = $matches[2][$i];
$item->url = $matches[1][$i];

$path = basename($item->url);                // каталог

echo $path;` не понятно как удалить ? и все после него из pfth

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно так

```
$last_url = 'https://вася.ру/каталог/';

$host = parse_url($last_url, PHP_URL_HOST); // вася.ру
$path = basename($last_url);                // каталог
```